# Random Level Generation with LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have made a class for the level generation and have got so far with it:

```
public class LevelGenerator {

private Sprite environment;
private float leftEdge, rightEdge, minGap, maxGap, y;

public Enemy enemy;

public LevelGenerator(Sprite environment, float leftEdge, float rightEdge,
        float minGap, float maxGap) {
    this.environment = environment;
    this.leftEdge = leftEdge;
    this.rightEdge = rightEdge;
    this.minGap = minGap;
    this.maxGap = maxGap;
}

public void generate(float topEdge){
    if(y + MathUtils.random(minGap, maxGap) < topEdge)
        return;

    y = topEdge;

    float x = MathUtils.random(leftEdge, rightEdge);

}
```

Basically, what I want to happen is for the enemy block to randomly generate on the sides of the screen. Here is the enemy block class (very simple):

```
public class Enemy extends Sprite{

public Enemy(Sprite sprite) {
    super(sprite);
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch spriteBatch){
    super.draw(spriteBatch);

    }

}
```

This is what the game looks like at the moment when the block is just simply drawn on the game screen in a static position: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOwXu.png. What I am trying to achieve is for these "enemy" blocks to spawn randomly on either side of the screen but I can't seem to figure out a way to do it with the code I have so far.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please draw lines where blocks should appear? Can blocks overlap each other?

Answer (score 0):

I could not test but I think it will be fine, you have a rectangle if you want to see if it collides with another actor, if so updates its position in the update and draw method, and ramdon method start customizing to see if the coordinates, which colicionan be assigned to another actor rectagulo enemy or bye.

```
public class overFlowEnemy extends Sprite {

 private final float maxH = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
 private final float maxW = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

 private Rectangle rectangle;

 private Random random = new Random();

 private float inttt = 0;
 private float randomN = 0;

 private boolean hasCollided = false; 

public overFlowEnemy(Sprite sprite) {
    super(sprite);

    crearEnemigo();

    rectangle = new Rectangle(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
 }

@Override
public void draw(Batch spriteBatch) {
    super.draw(spriteBatch);


}

private void crearEnemigo(){

    setX(RandomNumber((int)maxW));
    setY(RandomNumber((int)maxH));
}

private int RandomNumber(int pos) {

    random.setSeed(System.nanoTime() * (long) inttt);
    this.randomN = random.nextInt(pos);
    inttt += randomN;

    return (int)randomN;

}

public Rectangle getColliderActor(){
    return this.rectangle;
}
```

}

the class as this should create a random enemy.

Edit: rereading your question, is that my English is not very good, and I think you wanted to be drawn only on the sides of the screen if so, tell me or adapts the class because when you create thought, which was across the screen.

I just added another class, if you can and want to work as you tell me which is correct, and delete the other.

```
public class overFlow extends Sprite {

 private final float maxH = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
 private final float maxW = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

 private Rectangle rectangle;

 private Random random = new Random();

 private float inttt = 0;
 private float randomN = 0;

 private boolean hasCollided = false; 

public overFlow(Sprite sprite) {
    super(sprite);

    crearEnemigo();

    rectangle = new Rectangle(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
 }

@Override
public void draw(Batch spriteBatch) {
    super.draw(spriteBatch);


}

private void crearEnemigo(){

    setX(RandomNumber((int)maxW, true));
    setY(RandomNumber((int)maxH, false));
}

private int RandomNumber(int pos, boolean w) {

    random.setSeed(System.nanoTime() * (long) inttt);
    if (w = true){

        this.randomN = random.nextInt((pos));

            if(randomN % 2 == 0){
                randomN = (pos - getWidth()); 
            }else{
                randomN = 0; //left screen
            }
    }else{

        this.randomN = random.nextInt(pos - (int)getHeight());
    }
        inttt += randomN;

    return (int)randomN;

}

public Rectangle getColliderActor(){
    return this.rectangle;
}
```

}